# Omni Channel - Set different capacity per user

Tags: apex, omnichannel

I would like to assign cases to agents via Omni Channel, but I've seen capacity is set at Presence Configuration, and it's classified by profile, or user by user. Isn't there any way to do it by another object or without creating a lot of presence configurations? Because I would like to make it easy to manage.
I was thinking about a new field at Users object, setting current capacity for each of them, and call thar info from apex, but I'm actually searching if it is possible. My last option was setting presence status for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, we classified users into categories according experience: Level 01, Level 02 and Level 03, using those categories as Presence Configurations and assigning users to these ones.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this by creating multiple presence configurations, you will need to create `PresenceUserConfigUser` record.

DML operation not allowed on this object through APEX. So, you need to use screen flow.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use flow to create PresenceUserConfigUser record, but flow will throw error too .. :D
flow error : The flow failed to access the value for UserPresenceRecord.UserId because it hasn't been set or assigned.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/193950)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.